# Qt: How can I access the actual widgets on a page in WebKit?

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit, qwebview

Is there a way to access the widgets generated by `INPUT` and `SELECT` on a page in WebKit, using Qt?

On a related note, does WebKit provide these widgets, or does it delegate back to Qt to generate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything inside  in QWebView does not use the conventional Qt widget system. It's only HTML, rendered by WebKit. But you can access to html by using the evalJS function. Example of code:

```
 QString Widget::evalJS(const QString &js)
 {
     QWebFrame *frame = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame();
     return frame->evaluateJavaScript(js).toString();
 }

 evalJS(QString("document.forms[\"f\"].text.value = \"%1\";").arg(fromText));

 evalJS(QString("document.forms[\"f\"].langSelect.value = \"%1\";").arg(langText));

 evalJS(QString("translate()"));

 QString from = evalJS("document.forms[\"f\"].text.value");
 QString translation = evalJS("document.forms[\"f\"].translation.value");
 ui->textEditTo->setText(translation);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no "widgets". Newer browsers render all elements themselves to allow overlays etc.

If you want to manipulate them use the DOM.

Comment: Doesn't QtWebKit use the Qt widgets and pain system to draw the web page? QtWebKit depends on QtGui.

Comment: What about the interactive elements, like the text fields generated by INPUT?  They need to store information about selection, caret position, etc., so wouldn't they be some type of "widget" object?

Comment: @iconiK, @Jen: No. The lowest widget is the `QWebView` itself. Everything inside that does not use the conventional Qt widget system. It's rendered by [WebKit](http://webkit.org/).

Comment: @Troubadour, oh okay then. Well I guess there isn't any convenient way to manipulate the elements outside of QWebElement.

Comment: But... doesn't Qt provide callback methods to render each element?